# Image of a family of circles under $w = 1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, transformation

Given the family of circles $x^{2}+y^{2} = ax$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, I need to find the image under the transformation $w = 1/z$. I was given the hint to rewrite the equation first in terms of $z$, $\overline{z}$, and then plug in $z = 1/w$.

However, I am having difficulty doing this.

I completed the square in $x^{2}+y^{2}=ax$ to obtain $\left(x - \frac{a}{2} \right)^{2} + y^{2} = \left(\frac{a}{2} \right)^{2}$.

Then, given that $\displaystyle x = Re(z) = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle y = Im(z)= \frac{-(z-\overline{z})}{2i}$, I made those substitutaions and my equation became $\left( \frac{z+\overline{z}-a}{2}\right)^{2} - \left(\frac{\overline{z}-z}{2} \right)^{2} = \left(\frac{a}{2} \right)^{2}$.

Then, sbustituting in $z = \frac{1}{w}$, this became $\displaystyle \frac{\left(\frac{1}{w} + \frac{1}{\overline{w}} - a \right)^{2}}{4} - \frac{\left(\frac{1}{\overline{w}} - \frac{1}{w} \right)^{2}}{4} = \frac{a^{2}}{4}$.

Beyond this, my algebra gets very wonky.

Could someone please tell me what my final result should be? Knowing that would allow me to work backwards and then apply these methods to other problems (of which I have many to do!).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $z=x+iy$, so $x^2+y^2=z\bar{z}$, and $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$. Thus the circles can be described by
$$
z\bar{z}=a\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}
$$
Upon doing $z=1/w$, you get
$$
\frac{1}{w\bar{w}}=\frac{a}{2}\frac{\bar{w}+w}{w\bar{w}}
$$
that becomes
$$
a\frac{\bar{w}+w}{2}=1
$$
Writing $w=X+iY$, you get
$$
aX=1
$$

---

More generally, if you have the circle $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$, with $z=x+iy$ you get
$$
z\bar{z}+a\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}+b\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}+c=0
$$
Upon changing $z=1/w$, the equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{w\bar{w}}+a\frac{\bar{w}+w}{2w\bar{w}}
+b\frac{\bar{w}-w}{2iw\bar{w}}+c=0
$$
and removing $w\bar{w}$ from the denominator,
$$
1+a\frac{w+\bar{w}}{2}-b\frac{w-\bar{w}}{2i}+cw\bar{w}=0
$$
or, with $w=X+iY$,
$$
1+aX-bY+c(X^2+Y^2)=0
$$
So the circle becomes a straight line if $c=0$ (that is, it passes through the origin), otherwise it is transformed into a circle.

Similarly, the line $ax+by+c=0$ becomes
$$
a\frac{\bar{w}+w}{2w\bar{w}}+b\frac{\bar{w}-w}{2iw\bar{w}}+c=0
$$
and finally
$$
aX-bY+c(X^2+Y^2)=0
$$
so it becomes a circle if $c\ne0$, or a straight line through the origin otherwise.

Comment: in the specific case you mention above, where $X = \frac{1}{a}$, I suppose we're assuming that $a \neq 0$. What about the case where $a = 0$? Then, I get $\frac{1}{w}\cdot \frac{1}{\overline{w}} = 0$, and therefore that $\frac{1}{X^{2}+iY^{2}}=0$, which does not have a solution. So, does the case where $a = 0$ map to the point at infinity or something?

Comment: @JessyCat The case $a=0$ should be excluded, because it corresponds to a degenerate circle at the origin, which has no correspondent under the given transformation. Indeed, the mapping can be made bijective if one adds the point at infinity.

Comment: and so if we were going in the opposite direction, say transforming $Re z = a$ (okay, so maybe not exactly in the opposite direction) under $w = \frac{1}{z}$, would the case where $a = 0$ transform to the imaginary axis (not including the origin)?

Comment: @JessyCat I don't get it: $x=a$ becomes $\frac{\bar{w}+w}{2w\bar{w}}=a$, that is, $X=a(X^2+Y^2)$, which for $a\ne0$ is a circle and for $a=0$ is the line $X=0$.

Comment: yes. The line $X = 0$ is the imaginary axis. But you don't want to include the origin there, b/c then you'll end up dividing by 0 .

Comment: Why did you write $w=X+iY$ to get $aX=1$?

Comment: @Isa Because then $w+\bar{w}=2X$

Comment: And what is that used for?

Comment: What is the image of the family?

Comment: @Isa They’re the lines parallel to the $Y$-axis, except the axis itself.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be solved by [inversive geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry).  In (traditional circle) inversive geometry, we invert figures with respect to an *inversion circle* centered at (say) $O$ with radius $r$.  Each point $P$ inverts to a point $P'$ such that $O, P, P'$ all lie on a line, with $P$ and $P'$ on the same side of $O$, and with $OP \cdot OP' = r^2$.

[image]

One useful property of this inversion is that circles invert to other circles, or to lines.  (More about this in a moment.)  The transformation $w = \frac{1}{z}$ is almost inversive with respect to the unit circle at the origin, except that the result is also reflected across the $x$-axis.  However, since all the circles (including the unit circle at the origin) are symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis, we can ignore the reflection.

With that in mind, let us observe first that the family of circles all intersect the $x$-axis in two points: at $(0, 0)$ and at $(a, 0)$.

[image]

As mentioned above, all circles invert to either circles, or lines.  They invert to circles if they do not pass through the inversion circle's center, but if they do pass through that center, as they do here, they invert to lines.  Furthermore, if the circles intersect, as they also do here, that line passes through the two intersection points.  The distance of that line from the center is the reciprocal of the furthest distance of that *circle* from the center.  Since the circles have greatest distance $1, 2, 3, \ldots$, the distances of the lines from the center must be $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots$, as below:

[image]

So, in general, the circle

$$
x^2+y^2 = ax
$$

inverts to

$$
x = \frac{1}{a}
$$

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. :)

I would add that building these geometric constructions in a software like Geogebra is of great help.

Comment: @AlanMuniz: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @AlanMuniz: P.S. Inversive geometry is an intuitive answer to a lot of these kinds of questions.

Comment: Sure. And it leads to very simple solutions of very tricky questions such as finding a circle tangent to two other given circles...

Comment: Using a software one can see this in  few minutes and get the hints to work out the proofs...

Comment: @AlanMuniz: Who needs software? :-)

Comment: You didn't draw these images by hand. :p

Comment: @AlanMuniz: No, of course not, but I didn't need the software to *see* it! :-)

Comment: Neither did I. But for one that cannot see them yet...

Comment: @BrianTung (or Brian Griffin), what happens when $a = 0$? I.e., what is the image of $x^{2}+y^{2}=ax$ under $w = 1/z$ when $a = 0$?

Comment: @JessyCat: For that, it is necessary to introduce the so-called point at infinity (q.v.).  $x^2+y^2 = 0$ is a single point at the center of the inversion circle, and it inverts to that point at infinity.  (See the "inversive geometry" article at Wikipedia (linked in my answer above) for more details.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This transformation can be seen as successive transformations  $$Z = \frac{z}{|z|^2} , \,\,\,w = \overline {Z}$$

since $z \cdot \overline{z} = |z|^2$.

Then $z = \frac{1}{w} = \frac{\overline w}{|w|^2}$ and $$x = \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2} \,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\,\,y = \frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}$$

where $w = u + iv$.

**Edit:** Now study $$A(x^2+y^2) + Bx + Cy + D = 0$$

complete the square and make the substitutions to see that is taken to

$$D(u^2 + v^2) + Bu - Cv + A = 0 $$

which is a circle or a line., depending on whether $D \neq  0$ or $D=0.$

See what happens when a cirle $A \neq 0$ is passing or not through the origin.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Much clearer now.