# whats the image of this circle under the reciprocal mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, quasiconformal-maps

I need to find the image of $D(a,|a|)$ $a \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ under the transformation $f(z) = 1/z$.

I was trying write $z = |a|e^{i\theta} + a$ and then $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$ and see what kind of line I get, but I get to nowhere.

Comment: There are two very obvious points on the circle, $0$ and $2a$. Further note that $f$ maps the real axis (plus $\infty$) to itself. So what is the angle between the image of the circle and the real axis?

Comment: it should be zero?

Comment: What is the angle between the circle and the real axis at the intersection points?

Comment: Did you look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637621/image-of-a-family-of-circles-under-w-1-z?rq=1 ?

Comment: the image of $f$ at the real axis are the points $x$ such that $|x| > 2a$?